# Stuck on blue screen while booting the system

Tags: boot, 16.04

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I am stuck into blue screen with no message. 
Its just showing a cursor nothing else.
[image: booting]
[image: Screenshot]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This does not look like a Ubuntu 16.04 without extensive changes. Please add additional info to your question on how you changed your base install.

Comment: It is ubuntu 16.04 this screen appears after the boot process

Comment: In my case the issue popped up after installing `skypeforlinux` (from a `.deb` package downloaded from skype.com).  Switching to a character terminal, uninstalling it and then rebooting took me back to the previous (working) state.

Answer (score 49):

I fixed this by rebooting. At the login screen, I switched to a terminal <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and then running `sudo apt-get upgrade`. That would not run, but I was told to use `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. After I ran `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, then I ran `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Lastly, I ran `reboot`. This solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks, It's works for me, the short cut was ctrl+alt+f1 to switch to terminal

Comment: Same for me. Thank you. It solves the problem for my ub 16.04.

Comment: Unfortunately in my case screen turns black after pressing ctrl + alt + F1 . I can't find any terminal.

Comment: Worked for me! didnt have to do the second part, only sudo apt-get upgrade
using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: ctrl + alt + F3 did the trick for me, then dpkg fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I'm having the same problem - ctrl + alt +f1 & ctrl + alt + f3 does nothing; I have ubuntu 16.04 on virtual box on  windows 7 professional; can someone help (I keep getting the ubuntu blue screen)?

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me after installing Ubuntu 20.04 on VirtualBox.

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me a couple days ago. I waited until it said it had internal error, and I hard rebooted it (holding down power button).

On Ubuntu bootup, you have your OS selection screen. It's a purple screen showing your possible options for bootup. Use the arrow keys and goto Advanced Options for Ubuntu.

And then select: Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-31-generic (recovery mode)

It'll run a lot of code until you reach a link screen.

Do the fsck option, and it should clean and fix your OS, and do the dpkg option. It will repair the packages. And then reboot. This fixed mine.

And then if you want you can do clean to free up some space

Hope this helps, Dallin

Comment: Great, this worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: This does not work for segfault error 6 in libnvidia-glcore.so in Compiz.