# Problem with dpkg in recovery mode

Tags: 16.04, dpkg

I'm new to Linux (and also to Stack Exchange :)). I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop last week. It has a dual boot with Ubuntu and Windows 10. A strange problem occurred today.
Two days ago, when I tried to boot up Ubuntu, my PC showed a blue screen after I entered my password. My desktop wallpaper hadn't appeared when I was entering the password - I hadn't noticed it back then.

I forced a reboot and tried again. The same thing happened every time. Finally I booted Windows and shut down my PC.

Since then, I haven't used Ubuntu till today. Windows 10 works fine. Now, when Ubuntu failed to load, I started Recovery Mode (GNU GRUB screen appears). I tried failsafeX, and something like "no screen found" appeared and it went back to the recovery mode menu. Then I ran dpkg, and it is stuck at the following lines (Something like these, I don't exactly remember):

```
[OK] Started Braille Device Support
[OK] Started udev Kernel Device Manager
```

It has been stuck at this screen for the last 10 minutes. I'm afraid my data will get corrupted if I try to force a reboot. Please help!!

PS. I haven't interrupted any visible update or installation while shutting down my PC.

Comment: Did you insert any usb disks?

Comment: I only have the receiver of my wireless mouse inserted all the time....ever since I bought my laptop. Otherwise, no.

Comment: First of all welcome to the ubuntu  community. Please calm down and be patient.

Comment: You have a few ways to recover your ubuntu installation, such as live.iso in a dvd or live.iso in a usb.

Comment: I entered recovery mode and selected dpkg. I mean, I selected the dpkg option in a menu similar to this : http://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/650x361xubuntu-14.04-recovery-mode-menu.png.pagespeed.gp+jp+jw+pj+js+rj+rp+rw+ri+cp+md.ic.tJHIR7oEvc.png

Comment: When you attempted to login, did you reach DM login screen like this one http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-fgfBHvKwkEA/UiRqrTm9etI/AAAAAAAAEbE/qHxq6h5mDj8/s1000/lightdm-login.jpg?

Comment: Yes I did. But after entering my password, only a blue screen appeared.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears). Your desktop just looks different than in the linked question.

Comment: @DavidFoerster My desktop wallpaper does not load, and neither can I see my mouse cursor.
Even if I am to try the solution of the linked question, I have to open a terminal. dpkg is still running! How do I open a terminal from there?

Comment: What `dpkg` command did you issue? I doubt that it's still running.

Comment: If you have guest session in login screen you can try it.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I just solved the problem : I interrupted dpkg (Ctrl+C) and Ubuntu is running fine again. (In fact, I'm posting this from Ubuntu) There's only this popup in the title bar: 
"An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what's wrong. The error message was : ' Error: BrokenCount > 0'. This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies"
Do I need to do anything else now? 
Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to Linux. I think I have the same issue as you. I confront it while solving the blue screen issue following the last answer to this post 
[Stuck on blue screen while booting the system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/839279/stuck-on-blue-screen-while-booting-the-system) .

When I saw this information, I simply restart the computer by pressing the button and it recovered from the blue screen issue.

Hope this helps.