# dpkg stuck in viscious cycle in recovery mode

Tags: nvidia, dpkg, recovery-mode

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.3 on an Alienware laptop. In order to get the install media to boot I had to use `nouveau.modeset=0`. Also the installer would hang unless I unchecked the two boxes about installing updates and downloading third party drivers. I figured I would just update and install the drivers once I got the system booting.

Here's the problem. After installation I booted and I couldn't get past the login screen; figured it was because I didn't have the Nvidia drivers. So I booted to recovery mode and ran `apt update && apt upgrade`. But the upgrade command got stuck when it was trying to configure cups. Here are the last two lines before the hang:

```
invoke-rc.d: could not determine runlevel
[ OK ] Started Braille Device Support
```

So for some reason invoke-rc.d doesn't recognize my runlevel, I suspect it has to do with recovery mode. I'm pretty my problem is related to [this bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=823611;msg=9). Also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/869450/problem-with-dpkg-in-recovery-mode) looks similar, but it hasn't been resolved.

Well now I'm stuck in a vicious circle. If I try to install anything I get an error and a suggestion to run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Running that command gets stuck again because of the runlevel bug. And around and around.

**How can I reconfigure dpkg and install my video driver without get stuck in this cycle?**

Comment: What video card and what error(s) when you run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` ?

Comment: When I run that command I get back to the same error `invoke-rc.d: could not determine runlevel`

Answer (score 2):

At the login screen I was able to get to a tty `ctrl+alt+F3`. At the tty I ran

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

This time it succeeded because I wasn't in recovery-mode.

Finally I was able to install my video card driver

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

After rebooting I can log in fine. Seems like a bug to me though.

Comment: don't forget to mark your answer as the fix.