# Ubuntu 16.04 does not restart after blue screen

Tags: 16.04

I finally experienced the booting error in Ubuntu, where the screen turns blue and nothing works. 
I followed the first suggestion [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/839279/stuck-on-blue-screen-while-booting-the-system) and everything was fine:

1. I pressed Crl+Alt+F1 and entered the terminal
2. I run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and it told me to restart everything

However, then I have the login screen that does not go forward, being stucked as it appears below. I am still wating for it, however it's been 1 hour since when it started again and I am skeptical that everthing will improve all of a sudden. Moreover the Crl+Alt+F1 after the boot does not work anymore, when I switch it on again. 
What might be happening?

Jacopo

[Login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alRIN.jpg)

Comment: That's not the login screen (the login screen lets you sign in to your username). I think that's called the startup screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/162075/301745)

Comment: Not exactly. The screen is not white, there is the Ubuntu logo with the four dots, but nothing happens. I tried to use BOOT repair (Recommended repari) and still, nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered same issue twice and observed that I was setting wrong PATH variable during setting $ANDROID_HOME, so here what I did to make it fix.

1. Open terminal via ctrl+alt+f3.
2. Since wrong path was set, I was not able to run command like sudo, ls etc, I have ran

   ```
   export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"
   ```
3. Then I run command

   ```
    sudo nano /etc/environment
   ```
4. Removed all variables which was defined by me, leaving system's variable, I have typed

   ```
   export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"
   ```
5. And finally I ran

   ```
     sudo reboot
   ```

Hope this help, otherwise this problem occurs due to display drivers then please look at this
[Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: In my case it was impossible to proceed accordingly, as I was not able to access the terminal. I reinstalled everything. However, your suggestion could be useful.